# Point with many prescribed Lebesgue densities

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set and consider the function $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\frac{m(E\cap [-x,x])}{2x},$$

where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure. Assume that $F\subset [0,1]$. Is there any characerization for the sets, which satisfies $$f(0)=F,$$

where by $f(0)$, I mean the set of all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that, there is a sequence $a_n\to 0$ with $\lim_n f(a_n)=y$.

Comment: Since the set you're looking at is the set of all subsequential limits of a function at a point (also called the cluster set of the function at a point), and because all such sets are closed, the set you're interested in is a closed subset of $[0,1].$ I strongly suspect that any closed subset of $[0,1]$ can be realized as the set of subsequential Lebesgue densities for some fixed set at a fixed point (and thus, the characterization you seek is "closed subset of the unit interval"), but I don't know if the result is in the literature anywhere.

Comment: Incidentally, if you can prove that any countable subset of $[0,1]$ is a subset of the set of subsequential Lebesgue densities for some fixed set at a fixed point, then the result for arbitrary closed sets will follow, since every closed subset of $[0,1]$ is the closure of some countable subset of $[0,1].$

Comment: I think I can prove it for countable sets @DaveL.Renfro, however the argument goes to crazy and I can't wrap my head around it, but the idea is almost the same for the finite case, i.e., we write $\mathbb{N}\cup _{i=1}^\infty N_i$, where $N_i\cap N_j=\emptyset$ and $N_i$ is infinity. Now for each $N_i$, we associate a sequence of intervals, $[a_{ij},b_{ij}]$, which converges to $0$ and the union in $j$ has the density we want. I think this might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous for $x>0$. Hence, its  cluster set as $x\to 0^+$ is a closed interval, namely $[\alpha,\beta]$ where 
$\alpha=\liminf_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ and $\beta= \limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$. Indeed, there are sequences $a_n\to 0$ and $b_n\to 0$ such that $f(a_n)\to\alpha$ and $f(b_n)\to \beta$. Pick a number $\gamma\in (\alpha,\beta)$. By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ attains the value $\gamma$ somewhere between $a_n$ and $b_n$, for every sufficiently large $n$. Therefore, $\gamma$ is also in the cluster set, as claimed.

Thus, the characterization of such sets $F$ is: "closed subintervals of $[0,1]$". Every closed subinterval $[\alpha,\beta]\subset [0,1]$ is realized by a set of the form
$$E=\bigcup_n \{x: u_n\le |x|\le v_n\}$$ where the numbers $u_n$, $v_n$ are chosen so that 
$$\frac{1}{u_n}\sum_{k>n}(v_k-u_k)\to \alpha,\qquad \frac{1}{v_n}\sum_{k\ge n}(v_k-u_k)\to \beta$$

Comment: I started thinking about this again, maybe 30 minutes or so ago, and I realized the function under consideration is continuous (Lipschitz with constant $1$ in fact), so the cluster sets will be closed intervals, and so all one has to do is arrange for $\liminf \leq \limsup$ to be arbitrarily specified. (For some reason stackexchange has been intermittently down the past 30 minutes or more where I'm at, and I only just now got thorugh.) My earlier comment was based on confusing the actual function the OP defines with a pointwise defined density function.